# R Match character vectors

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching

var1 is a character vector

```
var1 <- c("tax evasion", "all taxes", "payment")
```

and var2 is another character vector

```
var2 <- c("bill", "income tax", "sales taxes")
```

Want to compare var1 and var2 and extract the terms which has a partial word match, for example, the desired answer in this case will be the following character vector:

```
"tax evasion", "all taxes", "income tax", "sales taxes"
```

I tried

```
sapply(var1, grep, var2, ignore.case=T,value=T)
```

but not getting the desired answer. How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need

```
lst1 <- strsplit(var1, ' ')
lst2 <- strsplit(var2, ' ')

indx1 <- sapply(lst1, function(x) any(grepl(paste(unlist(lst2), 
       collapse="|"), x)))
indx2 <- sapply(lst2, function(x) any(grepl(paste(unlist(lst1),
       collapse="|"), x)))
c(var1[indx1], var2[indx2])
#[1] "tax evasion" "all taxes"   "income tax"  "sales taxes"
```

If there are intersects between var1 and var2, wrap with with `unique` as @ColonelBeauvel did in his elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you akrun and Colonel Beauvel. Both your answers are elegant, although personally I prefer answers which use less nor none additional packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can do (I use magrittr package for clarity of the code):

```
library(magrittr)

findIn = function(u, v)
{
    strsplit(u,' ') %>%
        unlist %>%
        sapply(grep, value=T, x=v) %>%
        unlist %>%
        unique
}

unique(c(findIn(var1, var2), findIn(var2, var1)))
#[1] "income tax"  "sales taxes" "tax evasion" "all taxes"
```

Comment: in 2 mins I effectively have the time to copy it all and format :) I developped it on my side but you were quicker, did not see your answer when posting. Btw, if two lists have a common sentence, you need unique at the end.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `unique` is needed at the end.  I didn't meant that you copied.  I saw a similarity so I commented.

Comment: @akrun why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @akrun people also upvote and accept answers that do not use additional packages (eg magrittr). Your answer did not use additional packages. Although Colonel Beauvel answer is useful too.

Comment: @john If you insist, I will undelete it, though I liked ColonelBeauvel's elegant take on the problem