# How to fuzzy match two character vectors in r

Tags: r, matching, stringr, grepl, fuzzy

### Context

I have a `df`,where the `id` refers to a different person and the `fruits_eat` refers to the fruit that person eats. Also, I have a vector `fruits_list` storing a list of fruits.

### Question

I want to generate a new variable `fruits_in_list` to indicate whether a person ate one and more fruits in the `fruits_list`, but I don't know how to implement it in R.

### What I've done

I checked some answers, but none of them are very relevant to my problem, like.

1. [R Match character vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421384/r-match-character-vectors)
2. [Compare two character vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598134/compare-two-character-vectors-in-r)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+fuzzy+match+two+character+vectors
4. [How to run through list of keyword vectors and fuzzy match them to a different file (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993134/how-to-run-through-list-of-keyword-vectors-and-fuzzy-match-them-to-a-different-f)
5. [Matching strings with abbreviations; fuzzy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383882/matching-strings-with-abbreviations-fuzzy-matching)

### Reproducible code

```
fruits_Jack = c('XXappleYYY,lemon,orange,pitaya')
fruits_Rose = c('Navel orange,Blood orange,watermelon,cherry')
fruits_Biden= c('pitaya,cherry,banana')

fruits_list = c('apple', 'lemon', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'peach', 'pear')

df = 
  data.frame(id         = c('Jack', 'Rose', 'Biden'),
             fruits_eat = c(fruits_Jack, fruits_Rose, fruits_Biden))

> df
     id                                  fruits_eat
1  Jack                   apple,lemon,orange,pitaya
2  Rose Navel orange,Blood orange,watermelon,cherry
3 Biden                        pitaya,cherry,banana
```

### Expect output

```
df_expect = cbind(df, fruits_in_list = c(1, 1, 0))

> df_expect
     id                                  fruits_eat fruits_in_list
1  Jack                   apple,lemon,orange,pitaya              1
2  Rose Navel orange,Blood orange,watermelon,cherry              1
3 Biden                        pitaya,cherry,banana              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `stringr`, use `str_detect`, or `str_count` if you want a real count:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(fruits_in_list = +(str_detect(fruits_eat, paste0(fruits_list, collapse = "|"))),
         count = str_count(fruits_eat, paste0(fruits_list, collapse = "|")))
```

```r
     id                                  fruits_eat fruits_in_list count
1  Jack              XXappleYYY,lemon,orange,pitaya              1     3
2  Rose Navel orange,Blood orange,watermelon,cherry              1     3
3 Biden                        pitaya,cherry,banana              0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `data.table` and fast if else `fifelse()`, as well as the base R function `grepl()` to do the matching. The "l" on the end of `grepl()` stands for logical, and that means it will return a `TRUE` if the pattern is matched anywhere in the string given (`fruits_eat`), and a `FALSE` otherwise - this means it can be passed immediately to the test argument of the if else.

The key point here is that you can paste strings `"string1"` and `"string2"` together separated by `"|"`, and `"string1|string2"` matches for `"string1"` or `"string2"` inside `grepl()`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, fruits_in_list := fifelse(grepl(paste0(fruits_list,
                                            collapse = "|"), fruits_eat),1,0)]
df
      id                                  fruits_eat fruits_in_list
1:  Jack              XXappleYYY,lemon,orange,pitaya              1
2:  Rose Navel orange,Blood orange,watermelon,cherry              1
3: Biden                        pitaya,cherry,banana              0
```